# Preventing app pool shutdown when httpRuntime is disabled

Tags: asp.net, .net, iis, application-pool

We had to disable httpRuntime at the root directory level in IIS for our application.
It is then enabled at the child directories.

[image]

The setting looks like this at EnvMonitor:

`<system.web>
<httpRuntime enable="false"/>
</system.web>`

And like this at Api and Web:

`<system.web>
<httpRuntime enable="true"/>
</system.web>`

Because of the runtime disabled at the root level(EnvMonitor), any incorrect request coming in is leading to the app pool shutdown.
Example URL: http://localhost/EnvMonitor/badpath

Is there anyway this can be prevented ?
We want to keep httpRuntime disabled at the root directory (EnvMonitor).

Comment: Unless there is more details on what you have done and what is the error, I guess there would be no answer.

Comment: What *problem* do you believe is *solved* by having the runtime disabled in the root?